# How PayPal Rest API handling payment via Echeck?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am hosting a service based website. I am allowing the User to pay via Paypal account but I want to restrict the User to pay via Echeck. I believe the classic API has some setting to block check payment but I didn't find anything regarding this in Rest API reference document.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Express Checkout, you can set PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly to disable eChecks.

Answer (score 0):

You must set payment options to "IMMEDIATE_PAY". Solution in PayPal JAVA Rest API:

```
PaymentOptions paymentOptions = new PaymentOptions();
paymentOptions.setAllowedPaymentMethod("IMMEDIATE_PAY");

Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.setPaymentOptions(paymentOptions);
...
```

Successfully removes eCheck option without further configuration.